# Cannot get product of if statement to write to a new .txt file

Tags: java, filewriter

I'm working on a sales tool for my Java class and I'm able to get everything working except for writing my results to a new .txt file.  To give some backstory, I have a GUI that is writing data to a text file named out1.txt.  I am reading data back in from this file and displaying anything with computesales >= 8,000 in a JtextArea as shown in the code below.

```
 private void evaluateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    saleOutput.setText("");        
    SaleReader reader = new SaleReader();

    try
    {
        List<Sales> sale = reader.readSale("out1.txt");   
        for (Sales s : sale)
        {
            if(s.computeSales()>= 8000)
            {
            saleOutput.append(s.toString());
            saleOutput.append("\n");

            }
        }
    }catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Unable to open file");
        Logger.getLogger(MainApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
```

I have tried a variation of what I have below that writes to my out1.txt file, but it doesn't seem to work at all.  It won't even create the file.  My coworker seemed to think that it may be an issues with the filewriter not being flushed?

```
 public void writeSales(Sales s) throws IOException
{
    File testWriter = new File ("out1.txt");
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(testWriter, true));

    out.write("" + s.getSalesID());
    out.write(", ");
    out.write(s.getFirstName());
    out.write(", ");
    out.write(s.getLastName());
    out.write(", ");
    out.write("" + s.getOfficeSupplies());
    out.write(", ");
    out.write("" + s.getBooks());
    out.write(", ");
    out.write("" + s.getPaper());
    out.write(", ");
    out.write("" + s.getDistrictValue());        
    out.write(", ");
    out.write("" + s.getPreferredContact());   
    out.write(", ");
    out.write("" + s.computeSales());
    out.newLine();       
    out.close();
}
```

Here is what I'm writing in a separate class to write to the new stars.txt file, but is not working.  Any suggestions?

```
public void writeStars(Sales f) throws IOException
{
    File testStars = new File ("stars.txt");
    BufferedWriter outStars = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(testStars, true));
    SaleReader reader = new SaleReader();

     try
    {
        List<Sales> sale = reader.readSale("out1.txt");   
        for (Sales s : sale)
        {
            if(s.computeSales()>= 8000)
            {
            outStars.write("" + s.getDistrictValue());
            outStars.newLine();
            outStars.close();

            }
        }
    }catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I'm calling it from here.

```
public class Sales 
{
 private int salesID;
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private double officeSupplies;
 private double books;
 private double paper;
 private String districtValue;
 private String preferredContact;

public int getSalesID() {
    return salesID;
}

public void setSalesID(int salesID) {
    this.salesID = salesID;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public double getOfficeSupplies() {
    return officeSupplies;
}

public void setOfficeSupplies(double officeSupplies) {
    this.officeSupplies = officeSupplies;
}

public double getBooks() {
    return books;
}

public void setBooks(double books) {
    this.books = books;
}

public double getPaper() {
    return paper;
}

public void setPaper(double paper) {
    this.paper = paper;
}

public String getPreferredContact() {
    return preferredContact;
}

public void setPreferredContact(String preferredContact) {
    this.preferredContact = preferredContact;
}    

public String getDistrictValue() {
    return districtValue;
}

public void setDistrictValue(String districtValue) {
    this.districtValue = districtValue;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Sales{" + "salesID=" + salesID + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", officeSupplies=" + officeSupplies + ", books=" + books + ", paper=" + paper + ", districtValue=" + districtValue + ", preferredContact=" + preferredContact + '}';
}

public double computeSales()
{
    return officeSupplies + books + paper;
}
```

}

Comment: For a start move `outStars.close();` out of your loop - what problems are you facing ? errors ?

Comment: Just moved it out, ran it, no problems and no results

Comment: debug it to make sure that `s.computeSales()>= 8000` is true and the `for` loop is being entered into

Comment: @ScaryWombat you are most definitely onto something.  I'm not very experienced with debugging, but I entered a println into the loop and nothing came out.  It's working in the other class though.  Pardon my ignorance, but I'm not sure how it would work for one but not the other?

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the new method?

Comment: BTW, your `writeStars` throws `IOException` for some code and catches it for other

Comment: @ScaryWombat I'm not a smart man.   lol.  I'm very new to Java and I'm not 100% sure what all of the moving parts are doing just yet.  At a high level, it makes some sense, but how everything ties together is definitely still a mystery for me.  If I know that my statement evaluates to true for my JtextArea, is there no way to have it write to the new file?  Does it have to reside in a separate class?

Comment: In a different class is fine, but please show how you are calling this code

Comment: @ScaryWombat I edited my post with the source code at the bottom for your review.

Comment: **No you are not**  You need to show the code where you are calling `writeStars`

Comment: @ScaryWombat I finally get what you're saying.  I have been overlooking the fact that I called the `writeSales` method in my submit button, but I have NOTHING calling the `writeStars` method. Any suggestions for integrating the call into my `saleOutput`?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I got it to work!  Except it's only pulling in my districtValue and not my tostring.  Looks like I have some more work to do, but thank you for leading me in the right direction.  Just had an "aha" moment thansk to you!

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your class is called for example `SalesWriter` and you have this code in it

```
public void writeStars() throws IOException
{
    File testStars = new File ("stars.txt");
    BufferedWriter outStars = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(testStars, true));
    SaleReader reader = new SaleReader();

     try
    {
        List<Sales> sale = reader.readSale("out1.txt");   
        for (Sales s : sale)
        {
            if(s.computeSales()>= 8000)
            {
            outStars.write(s);
            outStars.newLine();

            }
        }
        outStars.close();

    }catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Then from your main code you can call it like

```
new SalesWriter ().writeStars ();
```

**edit**

See how I have removed the parameter to this method, as your are reading the file in this method anyway.

Comment: I have it writing to my stars.txt file now, but it's duplicating everything.  I will review this section and see if that is the root of my problem.

Comment: You should only need to call this code once. In fact `new FileWriter(testStars, true)` can be `new FileWriter(testStars, false)`

Comment: Thank you so much!  That was the root of the problem.  Thanks again for all of your help.  You connected some dots for me tonight.